# Question about the convergence of $\sum a_n$

Tags: real-analysis

If we have series $\sum a_n$ that converges, is it true that $|a_n| \leq 1$?
If so, why?

Comment: if it is convergent and you form a new series by adding one new (big) term at the beginning,will it remain convergent? Did you try to answer this question on your own, did you look at some examples?

Comment: If you know that the given series converges, then the infinite term goes to zero (the converse of this statement is not true). It does not mean that every term in absolute terms is less than 1. The first terms could be more than 1 For example take a geometric series with starting value 10 and a rate r=0.9 The series converges (do you know to which value?)

Comment: $a_1=2$, and $a_n=0$ for $n>1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's certainly not true for all n.

You can for example take the following :

$a_1 = 10$

$\forall n\geq 2,~ a_n=0$

And the series converges.

What you can however say is that if $\sum a_n$ converges, $lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} a_n =0$. This implies that $\exists n_0, \forall n\geq n_0, \lvert a_n\rvert\leq 1$

Answer (score 1):

It is true *eventually*. The summands cannot be bounded away from zero.

Answer (score 1):

Not for all $n \in \mathbb N$, but the convergence of the series implies $\lim_{n \to \infty } a_n = 0$, hence  for all $\epsilon > 0 $ we have $|{a_n}| < \epsilon$ if $n$ is large.

Comment: Your statement is ambiguous. It could be interpreted to mean that if $n$ is large enough, $|a_n| < \varepsilon$ for any positive $\varepsilon$.